# couldn't vs wouldn't

Tags: word-usage

Let see this example:

1. I hid the presents so that she **wouldn't** find them.
2. I hid the presents so that she **couldn't** find them.

[The dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would) said:

> *so that/in order that somebody/something would*: used for saying why somebody does something

and  it didn't say the meaning of *would*.

Is **would**" the past form of "**will**"?
and "will" is used to predict something.

and "**could**" the past form of "**can**"?

Comment: To what does *it* refer?

Comment: See definition 4 of the dictionary you link to.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto @matias, but let me add that the more common situation is that "would" indicates intention and "could" indicates ability. If you said, "I asked Bob for help but he couldn't help me", you are saying that Bob was unable to help you. Maybe he wanted to help you, maybe not, but it doesn't matter because he was not able. If you said, "I asked Bob for help but he wouldn't help me", you are saying that he was able to help but he refused.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, **would** is used to express a *likely situation*, and **could** is used to express *ability in the past*.

You say "I hid the presents so that she couldn't find them" if you hid the presents in a place **you were absolutely certain it was *impossible* she would find them in**, and "I hid the presents so that she wouldn't find them" if you hid them in a place in which ***you predicted at that moment she would not find them in**, it was **unlikely**, yet it was possible.

The difference is of *impossibility* vs. *unlikeliness*.

Further information can be found on the [Merriam Webster Learner's Dictonary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/could-can-and-would), [here](https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-should-could-and-would/), and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49597/wouldnt-vs-wont-couldnt-vs-cant) is a similar question, though not the same.